# How can I debug a Dataflow error that does not produce logs?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am writing at Google Dataflow batch pipeline using the Python SDK and I have come across a pipeline failure that does not appear to have any logs in Stackdriver. The failure occurs while running `beam.combiners.ToList()` on a dataset ~300MB.

Stackdriver outputs:

> The job failed because a work item has failed 4 times. Look in previous log entries for the cause of each one of the 4 failures. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors. The work item was attempted on these workers:

However there are no logs I can find on why this is failing. I am running python3.6 and apache_beam==2.19.0. I am also running `--experiments=shuffle_mode=service`, which I am not sure is related.

What are my next steps for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have already tried to search for previous logs entries, but I was wondering if you have filtered by Error-level and Fatal-level as recommended in [The job failed because a work item failed 4 times](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#job-failed-four-times)? In this link you will find that there could be 4 similar errors which can be the cause of the failure.

In addition, you can add debug messages to verify your steps are flowing well, please refer to [Adding log messages to your pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#AddingLogging) for more information about it.

Comment: I think my problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892476/google-dataflow-wall-time-pcollection-output-numbers-going-backwards. I am still unable to find any logs telling me a worker has crashed but I am seeing the same symptoms of the wall time reversing and the output collection counts decreasing